# How to Unlock feature classes in ArcCatalog that don't show user

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arccatalog

In ArcCatalog there are some feature classes that are locked and don't show a user. After restarting SQL server, the feature classes remain locked. Any ideas as to what might be causing this and how I can unlock them?

Map services should have a user name like gisreader or something attached to them.

[image]

Versions: ArcCatalog version 10.1, SQL Server 2008r2 and SDE 10.0.

Comment: Are you serving any of these layers to GISSERVER/ web mapping applications?

Comment: @GISKid YES we are.

Comment: That could be the culprit. However, looking at mine it says"Lock Owner DBO".
What's under the "Connections" tab?

Answer (score 3):

I have this query stored away for all too frequent uses like this...

```
select  distinct p.[owner] as login, p.nodename, p.direct_connect, p.start_time, p.sde_id
        , r.database_name, r.[owner] as db_owner, r.table_name, l.registration_id
        , count(p.sde_id) connections
from sde_table_locks l inner join sde_table_registry r on l.registration_id = r.registration_id 
        inner join sde_process_information p on l.sde_id = p.sde_id
group by p.[owner], p.nodename, p.direct_connect, p.start_time, p.sde_id 
        , r.database_name, r.[owner], r.table_name, l.registration_id
```